# Accessing local storage in computed property

Tags: local-storage, nuxt.js

I'm trying to record some user preferences in the local storage for ease of use of my website. I wrote this code and it seems to work.

```html
<template>
    <v-data-table
      //... item binds etc
      :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
      @update:items-per-page="itemsPerPageUpdated"
    >
</template>

<script>
  // ...
  data: () => ({
    // ...
    _itemsPerPage: 10,
  }),

  computed: {
    itemsPerPage() {
      this._itemsPerPage = localStorage.getItem("itemsPerPageDevice") || 10
      return parseInt(this._itemsPerPage, 10)
    },
    // ...
  methods: {
    itemsPerPageUpdated(val){
      this._itemsPerPage = val;
      localStorage.setItem("itemsPerPageDevice", val);
    },

  },

</script>
```

But I'm not sure where the computed properties fall in the nuxt life cycle. I had an error in the docker environment that said "localStorage not defined" but never had this error outside of docker.

My questions is, is it okey to access the localStorage in computed properties in nuxt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is ok but only in client side so you need to check `process.client` before using `localStorage`:

```js
computed: {
    itemsPerPage() {
      if (process.client) {
        this._itemsPerPage = localStorage.getItem("itemsPerPageDevice") || 10
        return parseInt(this._itemsPerPage, 10)
      } else {
        return 10
      }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution above to see if `localStorage` is defined in your context (`window`'s API can only be accessed on client-side, hence not on server while being SSR'ed).

You could make a test like `process.client` or use one of the packages aimed towards a universal single usage and bothering anymore with those conditions:

- https://github.com/unjs/unstorage
- https://github.com/nuxt-community/universal-storage-module

Comment: Thanks for the resources. I'm currently using cookie-universal-nuxt for data access in ssr. Handling redis access in the backend, but this unstorage package looks very good, i'll keep that in my for future projects.